# LocalHost: Not receiving Form To Email with PHP

Tags: java, php, html, css

My problem is that I am getting the email_success.php page, but when I go to check my email there is nothing there. I am using LocalHost USBWebServer V8. Any help would appreciated!`
Here is the html contact form:

```
<html xslms="http: //www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html: charset-UTF-8">
<title>Contact Form</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Contact Form</h1>
<form action="thankyou.php" method="post">
    Name <input type="text" name="fullname"><br>
    Email <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    Message <textarea name="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">





</body>
</html>
```

And this is the php for the thankyou.php and the email_success.php pages:

```
<?php


$name = $_POST['fullname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

$email_message = "

Name: ".$name."
Email: ".$email."
Message: ".$message."
";


mail ('ENTERYOUREMAILHERE@gmail.com', 'New inquiry', $email_message);
header("Location: email_success.php");



?>

************************************************
<html xslms="http: //www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html: charset-UTF-8">
<title>Contact Form</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Email Sent</h1>
<p> Yippee! Your email has been sent </p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: mail() as far as I know does not work with Localhost..so you should check phpmailer or swiftmailer

Comment: I was suspecting this! Thanks for the confirmation, so as far as my actual code, there is no errors right?

Comment: verify by echoing the values so you know you are getting what you are supposed to and hence the code is right..also in $email_message you are using " so you don't need to break the " to add the variables.. you can write them directly within the ". I think the code is right but do verify it yourself

Comment: Bit of advice, you may want to test things on a web host.

Answer (score 0):

Well, working with a local server limits you some of the perks such as the ability to send emails since it doesn't come with an SMTP server. Now, assuming that your code has no errors, you could try using some tools that mimic such activities locally such as the [Test Mail Server Tool](https://toolheap.com/test-mail-server-tool/). I'm currently using it on my machine to test mail activities such as sending contact forms, verification codes and resetting passwords paired with **WAMP Server** so I'm not sure if it works with **USBWebServer** (*let me know when you try*).